# C++ connection to Azure SQL or Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: c++, sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I am trying to establish a connection to a database in my C++ code; however, I am unsure how to do so. My database is Azure SQL which uses microsoft sql server as the backend. Could someone provide me a website or code that executes the connection with the server name, database name, username, and pass?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To find the connection string, first login to [Azure portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com), then click your database > Show database connection strings, and you'll see the connection strings for ADO.NET, ODBC, PHP, JDBC.
[image]

For c++ code sample of connecting to Azure SQL Database, you can refer to this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630643.aspx , use the ODBC connection string of your database.

Comment: This sounds like the right approach here.@Infinity does this work for you?