# Integrate with Azure App Services via C++ UWP App

Tags: c++, azure, win-universal-app, azure-mobile-services

What is the best way of integrating with an SQLServer DB hosted in Azure App Services from a C++ XAML UWP app?

The samples are C# based using azure mobile services SDK.  I may be able to wrap this in a C# runtime component?  Or is there an alternative?

After looking at the SDK it appears to be simple HTTP requests under the hood so if the API is documented I could use that directly?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: A wrapper is one option, however you should be able to just connect to the database using the connection string and passwords just like any other DB. I would take a look at this: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn630643.aspx)  and this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35556143/c-connection-to-azure-sql-or-microsoft-sql-server)

Comment: Thanks SammyG, I had seen that article but unfortunately he is referring to desktop apps.  The ODBC API is not available to UWP apps.

Comment: After further research it appears that Microsoft don't want to give the ability to connect directly using Windows Store Apps UWP. They suggest using Local Storage like SQLite and synchronising data over a REST API. This is a better approach for security as it does mean the security can be tightened up further e.g. making the DB not public facing. Another reason They are doing this is to make you use more azure services. e.g. SDK's VMs, Services. For best design use REST(OData Service), just means it will take you longer to implement. In summary it seems Microsoft have deliberately left this ou

Comment: [Here](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/9327945-uwp-sql-server-api) you can see people are not happy. the only option is a form of web service.

Comment: Thanks SammyG, I've added my vote!

Answer (score 2):

Once you create an Azure App Service Mobile App, the backend will expose an OData v3 (with some enhancements).  You will need to add an additional header (see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-client-and-server-versioning/), and deal with the specifics that are required for offline sync (such as the Id field being a string GUID, not an auto-incrementing int).  However, you should be able to just use an OData v3 client.  Check out https://github.com/OData/odatacpp-client as a project that could be used as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Mobile Services replaced with Azure Mobile Apps. You can find Mobile Apps on new [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com)
Code is very similar to Mobile Services.
Here is tutorial how to start: [Create a Windows app](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/)
By the way, you it's very simple to have SQLite database and synchronize data with Cloud SQL Server DB.
[Offline Data Sync in Azure Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync/)

After you create a Mobile App, you'll get possibility to download client application sample. But it's for 8.1 and C#.
If shortly:
Install from NuGet Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client

In App.xaml.cs add

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices;
```

And declaration:

```
public static MobileServiceClient MobileService =
     new MobileServiceClient("https://mydemomobservice.azurewebsites.net");
```

And also it's required to create class with database structure:

```
   public class mydemotable
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "surname")]
    public string surname { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "salary")]
    public int salary { get; set; }
}
```

Field Id is required.

After this you can do something like:

```
            mydemotable item = new mydemotable
        {
            surname = "Skywalker",
            salary = 10000
        };
        await App.MobileService.GetTable<mydemotable>().InsertAsync(item);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. That has definitely given me a starting point.